# ubuntu on hyper-v gets smbus uninitialized error

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, hyper-v

when I try to run Ubuntu on Hyper-V virtual machine, it gives me this error and doesn't let me continue:

> piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.0: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade
>   BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr

what exactly do I have set up wrong? i'm giving it a 64gb hardrive with 1024 startup ram and 512mb - 4096 dynamic ram. If you need more information, please let me know how to find it as i'm just starting out using this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error trying "Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop 64 bits" on Hyper-V 2008 R2 when chosen to just try Ubuntu.

- First ensure your Hyper-V is up-to-date.
- Then install Ubuntu basically in your VM  but don't choose to run installation updates
- Next time you will run its updates. SMbus bug will fixed.
  Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this happens, but I can confirm [this](http://fintastical.blogspot.co.nz/2010/11/virtualbox-piix4smbus-error.html) worked for me using Ubuntu 12.04.2 on Hyper-V.

Basically, they are instructions on disabling the i2c_piix4 module.

Comment: Do you know what the effect of disabling i2c_piix4 is? What is it needed for?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me today. I installed Ubuntu 18.4.2 LTS and I got that error. I waited a few seconds and then it just continued.

I am using Hyper-V Core 2012 R2 with latest updates. I have 2 dual core Xeon processors with an old Motherboard. I was worried about the BIOS not supporting it.

Hope this helps.